# Ionic Platform ready fires every time the page is navigated through router

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, angular-router

I have the following piece of code in my constructor on a page **goPremium**

```
constructor(
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private iap2: InAppPurchase2) {
   
    s.iap2.verbosity = this.iap2.DEBUG;
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log('❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎Platform Ready❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎❤︎')
      this.setupProducts(); // Should be called ONLY ONCE. 
      this.iap2.refresh();
    });

  }
```

The `setupProducts()` function needs to be called only once, as it sets up the in-app products from the app store.
The code works just fine if the page is navigated through a touch of bottom tabs.

However, if I use routing from another page, the platform ready triggers again.

```
this.router.navigate(['tabs/gopremium', {accType: type}]);
```

So duplicate events get registered, which results in functions getting executed multiple times.

According to documentation, platform ready should fire only once.

I also tried it in `ionViewDidLoad`

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => { 
          this.setupProducts(); // Should be called ONLY ONCE. 
          this.iap2.refresh();
    });
  }
```

If I use this, the `setupProducts()` is not even firing once.

How to make `this.setupProducts()` to fire only once, even if the page is navigated through `this.router.navigate`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,

Instead of passing parameters like this

```
this.router.navigate(['tabs/gopremium', {accType: type}]);
```

It should be passed like this

```
this.router.navigate(['/tabs/gopremium'], { queryParams: { accType: 'Platinum' }});
```

In order for the platform ready to not fire every single time, the page is navigated.